# Как правильно сделать namespace для BX.ajax.runAction?

Tags: php, битрикс

Пытаюсь использовать контроллеры битрикса для ajax запроса к своему модулю через BX.ajax.runAction.

В корне модуля лежит .settings.php со следующим содержимым:

```
return [
'controllers' => [
    'value' => [
        'namespaces' => [
            '\\Evsyukov\\Main\\Controller' => 'api',
        ],
    ],
    'readonly' => true,
],
```

];

название модуля 'testmodules' далее /lib/controller/test.php
его код

```
namespace Evsyukov\Main\Controller;
```

class Book extends Controller {

```
public function configureActions()
{

    return [
        'greet' => [
            'prefilters' => [

            ]
        ]
    ];
}


public function addBookAction()
{
    $context = Application::getInstance()->getContext();
    $request = $context->getRequest();
    $arRequest = $request->getPostList()->toArray();

    $this->addbook($arRequest);

}
```

}

пытаюсь вызвать так

BX.ajax.runAction('evsyukov:main.api.book.addbook', {}

Answer (score 0):

В `configureActions()` у вас ключ `greet`, а метод назвали `addBook`, вот так должно быть. Также метод должен возвращать массив.

```php
<?php

namespace Evsyukov\Main\Controller;

use Bitrix\Main\Application;
use Bitrix\Main\Engine\Controller;
use Bitrix\Main\Engine\ActionFilter;

class Book extends Controller {
    
    public function configureActions()
    {
        return [
            'addBook' => [
                'prefilters' => [
                    new ActionFilter\Authentication(),
                    new ActionFilter\HttpMethod(
                        [
                            ActionFilter\HttpMethod::METHOD_GET,
                            ActionFilter\HttpMethod::METHOD_POST,
                        ]
                    ),
                    //new ActionFilter\Csrf(),
                ],
                'postfilters' => []
            ]
        ];
    }
    
    public function addBookAction()
    {
        $context = Application::getInstance()->getContext();
        $request = $context->getRequest();
        $arRequest = $request->getPostList()->toArray();
        
        return $arRequest;
    }
}
```

Comment: Переделал, всё равно не получается, пишет постоянно ошибку Could not find description of api.test.books in Bitrix\Main\Engine\DefaultController, такая ошибка возникает при любом раскладе, такое ощущение что он не может достучаться до класса в .setting.php, все попытки менять неймспейсы не привело к успеху

Comment: Модуль ваш корректно показывается в Битриксе? Модуль установлен? Какие-нибудь методы модуля на простой страничке отрабатываются?

Answer (score 0):

Если название модуля не содержит ".", то битрикс считает, что модуль его и ищет среди своих модулей в namespace Bitrix. Чтобы для вашего модуля работал механизм контроллеров, имя модуля должно быть evsyukov.main

И в .settings.php надо добавить defaultNamespace:

```
return [
'controllers' => [
    'value' => [
        'defaultNamespace' => '\\Evsyukov\\Main\\Controller',
        'namespaces' => [
            '\\Evsyukov\\Main\\Controller' => 'api',
        ],
    ],
    'readonly' => true,
],
```